# In a radar chart in matplotlib, is there any way to stagger the positions of the yticks (or rticks) so that they do not appear in the same line?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, radar-chart

I have the following code from the matplotlib demo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.spines import Spine
from matplotlib.projections.polar import PolarAxes
from matplotlib.projections import register_projection

import glob
import pygal
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def radar_factory(num_vars, frame='circle'):
    """Create a radar chart with `num_vars` axes.

    This function creates a RadarAxes projection and registers it.

    Parameters
    ----------
    num_vars : int
        Number of variables for radar chart.
    frame : {'circle' | 'polygon'}
        Shape of frame surrounding axes.

    """
    # calculate evenly-spaced axis angles
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num_vars, endpoint=False)
    # rotate theta such that the first axis is at the top
    theta += np.pi/2

    def draw_poly_patch(self):
        verts = unit_poly_verts(theta)
        return plt.Polygon(verts, closed=True, edgecolor='k')

    def draw_circle_patch(self):
        # unit circle centered on (0.5, 0.5)
        return plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.5)

    patch_dict = {'polygon': draw_poly_patch, 'circle': draw_circle_patch}
    if frame not in patch_dict:
        raise ValueError('unknown value for `frame`: %s' % frame)

    class RadarAxes(PolarAxes):
        name = 'radar'
        # use 1 line segment to connect specified points
        RESOLUTION = 1
        # define draw_frame method
        draw_patch = patch_dict[frame]

        def fill(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """Override fill so that line is closed by default"""
            closed = kwargs.pop('closed', True)
            return super(RadarAxes, self).fill(closed=closed, *args, **kwargs)

        def plot(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """Override plot so that line is closed by default"""
            lines = super(RadarAxes, self).plot(*args, **kwargs)
            for line in lines:
                self._close_line(line)

        def _close_line(self, line):
            x, y = line.get_data()
            # FIXME: markers at x[0], y[0] get doubled-up
            if x[0] != x[-1]:
                x = np.concatenate((x, [x[0]]))
                y = np.concatenate((y, [y[0]]))
                line.set_data(x, y)

        def set_varlabels(self, labels):
            self.set_thetagrids(np.degrees(theta))  #labels

        def _gen_axes_patch(self):
            return self.draw_patch()

        def _gen_axes_spines(self):
            if frame == 'circle':
                return PolarAxes._gen_axes_spines(self)
            # The following is a hack to get the spines (i.e. the axes frame)
            # to draw correctly for a polygon frame.

            # spine_type must be 'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom', or `circle`.
            spine_type = 'circle'
            verts = unit_poly_verts(theta)
            # close off polygon by repeating first vertex
            verts.append(verts[0])
            path = Path(verts)

            spine = Spine(self, spine_type, path)
            spine.set_transform(self.transAxes)
            return {'polar': spine}

    register_projection(RadarAxes)
    return theta


def unit_poly_verts(theta):
    """Return vertices of polygon for subplot axes.

    This polygon is circumscribed by a unit circle centered at (0.5, 0.5)
    """
    x0, y0, r = [0.5] * 3
    verts = [(r*np.cos(t) + x0, r*np.sin(t) + y0) for t in theta]
    return verts


def example_data():
    # The following data is from the Denver Aerosol Sources and Health study.
    # See  doi:10.1016/j.atmosenv.2008.12.017
    #
    # The data are pollution source profile estimates for five modeled
    # pollution sources (e.g., cars, wood-burning, etc) that emit 7-9 chemical
    # species. The radar charts are experimented with here to see if we can
    # nicely visualize how the modeled source profiles change across four
    # scenarios:
    #  1) No gas-phase species present, just seven particulate counts on
    #     Sulfate
    #     Nitrate
    #     Elemental Carbon (EC)
    #     Organic Carbon fraction 1 (OC)
    #     Organic Carbon fraction 2 (OC2)
    #     Organic Carbon fraction 3 (OC3)
    #     Pyrolized Organic Carbon (OP)
    #  2)Inclusion of gas-phase specie carbon monoxide (CO)
    #  3)Inclusion of gas-phase specie ozone (O3).
    #  4)Inclusion of both gas-phase species is present...
    data = [
        ['Sulfate', 'Nitrate', 'EC', 'OC1', 'OC2', 'OC3', 'OP', 'CO', 'O3'],
        ('Basecase', [
            [0.88, 0.01, 0.03, 0.03, 0.00, 0.06, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.07, 0.95, 0.04, 0.05, 0.00, 0.02, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.02, 0.85, 0.19, 0.05, 0.10, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.02, 0.01, 0.07, 0.01, 0.21, 0.12, 0.98, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.71, 0.74, 0.70, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]]),
        ('With CO', [
            [0.88, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.00, 0.05, 0.00, 0.05, 0.00],
            [0.08, 0.94, 0.04, 0.02, 0.00, 0.01, 0.12, 0.04, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.01, 0.79, 0.10, 0.00, 0.05, 0.00, 0.31, 0.00],
            [0.00, 0.02, 0.03, 0.38, 0.31, 0.31, 0.00, 0.59, 0.00],
            [0.02, 0.02, 0.11, 0.47, 0.69, 0.58, 0.88, 0.00, 0.00]]),
        ('With O3', [
            [0.89, 0.01, 0.07, 0.00, 0.00, 0.05, 0.00, 0.00, 0.03],
            [0.07, 0.95, 0.05, 0.04, 0.00, 0.02, 0.12, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.02, 0.86, 0.27, 0.16, 0.19, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.03, 0.00, 0.32, 0.29, 0.27, 0.00, 0.00, 0.95],
            [0.02, 0.00, 0.03, 0.37, 0.56, 0.47, 0.87, 0.00, 0.00]]),
        ('CO & O3', [
            [0.87, 0.01, 0.08, 0.00, 0.00, 0.04, 0.00, 0.00, 0.01],
            [0.09, 0.95, 0.02, 0.03, 0.00, 0.01, 0.13, 0.06, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.02, 0.71, 0.24, 0.13, 0.16, 0.00, 0.50, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.03, 0.00, 0.28, 0.24, 0.23, 0.00, 0.44, 0.88],
            [0.02, 0.00, 0.18, 0.45, 0.64, 0.55, 0.86, 0.00, 0.16]])
    ]
    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 24
    theta = radar_factory(N, frame='circle')

    folder = glob.glob('/*.csv',recursive=True)
    data = folder[0]
    data = pd.read_csv(data)
    unique_hours = data['Hour'].unique().reshape(1, -1)
    unique_hours = unique_hours.tolist()
    hourly_alarm = np.empty((24, 1))
    for i in range(0, 24):
        hourly_alarm[i] = data.loc[data['Hour'] == i, 'Number of Alarms'].sum()
    hourly_alarm = hourly_alarm.reshape(1, -1)
    hourly_alarm = hourly_alarm.tolist()
    unique_hours[0].sort()
#    data = example_data()
    data = []
    data.extend(unique_hours)
    data.extend(hourly_alarm)


    spoke_labels = data.pop(0)

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 9), nrows=1, ncols=1,
                             subplot_kw=dict(projection='radar'))
    #fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.25, hspace=0.20, top=0.85, bottom=0.05) #This line adjusts the amount of space between suplots. Not applicable here

    colors = ['b', 'r', 'g', 'm', 'y']
    # Plot the four cases from the example data on separate axes
    axes.set_title('Blah', weight='bold', size='medium', position=(0.5, 1.1),
                     horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
    axes.scatter(theta, data[0])
```

This gives me a plot like this:
[image]

Here, I want to stagger the positions of the ylabels on the theta axis so that they do not appear in one line and do not look good.

Can I be pointed in the direction as to how to do this?
I tried to change the attributes of the PolarAxes class but it is not working.

Comment: This can't be done easily. I can think of one way to do it, but it would be a bit of a hack..

Comment: Yes sure. Can you give me an outline of the type of hack you are thinking of?